# You have requested a non-existent parameter "name" error when trying to load a template using Symfony templating component

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-components

I am using the Symfony templating component to add templating functionality to the project I am working on, I am following the docs [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/templating.html) but I am using the service container Symfony component and adding the code in the docs using this code:

```
$containerBuilder->register('template_name_parser', Symfony\Component\Templating\TemplateNameParser::class);
$containerBuilder->register('file_system_loader', Symfony\Component\Templating\Loader\FilesystemLoader::class)
    ->setArguments([realpath('./') . '/app/Views/%name%']);
$containerBuilder->register('templating', Symfony\Component\Templating\PhpEngine::class)
    ->setArguments([new Reference('template_name_parser'), new Reference('file_system_loader')]);
```

But when I try to load a template file using this code:

```
container->get('templating')->render('home.php')
```

I get this error:

> Something went wrong! (You have requested a non-existent parameter
>   "name".)

Comment: Take a look at this line: `->setArguments([realpath('./') . '/app/Views/%name%'])` in DI world it'll expect a `%name%` parameter, which is being missing.

Comment: Thank you, after reviewing more of the docs I found a way to escape strings so there are not treated as parameters as you mentioned, I will post the solution as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as @yceruto mentioned Symfony DI will treat strings between `%%` as parameters so to escape it we need to add `%` in front of those strings as mentioned [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/parameters.html), so I updated my code like this:

```
$containerBuilder->register('file_system_loader', Symfony\Component\Templating\Loader\FilesystemLoader::class)
->setArguments([realpath('./') . '/app/Views/%%name%']);
```